# How to skip the function having errors and continue to the next function in Python

Tags: function, python-2.7, error-handling

Suppose i run a Python script having lets say 3 human-defined functions. If error occurs in 2nd functions and i want my script to execute 1st function then skip the error functions(2nd function) and execute the next, i.e the 3rd function. How to do?
i tried lots of answers have but not working in my case

Eg.

```
def value(a): # here is error, i intentionally assigned value of 'c' after the condition 
    b=a+c
    c=5
    print b


def value2(a): # error free
    c=5
    b=a+c
    print b


value2(5)#function calling
value(10)
```

so, error will come in **value** function and i want to skip this and proceed to **value2** function and execute it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the [try and except statement](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) in python.

What the try and except statement does is that first the code inside the try statement will run and if there is an error, the code inside the except statement will run.

For example:

```
try:
    a = b
except:
    a = 5
```

In this case, the code inside of the try statement would give an error, so the code inside the except statement would be run instead, setting a to be 5.

You can also use the try statement without putting any code in the except statement:

```
try:
    a = b
except:
    pass
```

Pass pretty much says "nothing to look at here"

What you want to do is as follows:

```
try:
    value2(5)
except:
    pass

try:
    value(10)
except:
    pass
```